Powers of an irrational number that are near integers
Online, I found $(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})^n$ approximately an integer if $n$ is an integer and $n\rightarrow\infty$.
I tried researching to find more of these numbers, and I found $(a+\sqrt{b})^n+(a-\sqrt{b})^n$ is always an integer, and $(a-\sqrt{b})^n$ approaches $0$ if $-1<a-\sqrt{b}<1$.
If $(a-\sqrt{b})^n=0$ while $n\rightarrow\infty$, $(a+\sqrt{b})^n+(a-\sqrt{b})^n\rightarrow(a+\sqrt{b})^n$ meaning as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $(a+\sqrt{b})^n$ is approximately an integer.
This gives infinite solutions, but not all the solutions, since $(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})^n$ still is a solution.
What are all the solutions for $a$ such that $a^n$ is approximately an integer as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

It does not approach "an integer". True, its fractional part goes to zero, but it does not approach a single number; it diverges to infinity. If that's what you meant, please edit your question to reflect that.

That power does not approach an integer - the sequence is unbounded. What you mean is that it is approximately an integer, and the approximation has limit $0$. You will find more examples looking at solutions to Pell's equation  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation . Those irrationals may find all the numbers you ask about.

For what you seem to want, you can take a monic  integer coefficient with one real root larger than $1$  and the other roots of magnitude less than one. For eaxample $x^3 - x -1$  has a real root about 1.3247, with powers very close to integers. A little caution is needed, $x^5 - x - 1$  has some complex roots of magnitude larger than one.

Look up Pisot numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number
